# array of dates with query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hope someone can help me on this.

I have this code.

```
$calendar->highlighted_dates = Array('2016-12-03', '2016-12-14', '2016-12-25' );
```

With it, i can have the dates highlighted in a calendar.

I'm Trying to get the same thing with a query using this code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event Order by Date");
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $Date.= "'".$row["Date"]."'".", "; 
            }
$arrayb=array("$Date");
$calendar->highlighted_dates = $arrayb;
```

If i echo $Date i get

> '2016-12-03', '2016-12-14', '2016-12-25',

But if i Print_r ($arrayb) i get

> Array([0]=>'2016-12-03', '2016-12-14', '2016-12-25',)

And nothing on Calendar.
I guess the problem is the [0]=>, but i don't know how to remove it.

Thanks.

**Final Code as suggested by [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker):**

```
$link=   mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("cannot connect"); 
 $dateArray = array();
   $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM event Order by Date");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ $dateArray[] = $row["Date"]; }
$calendar->highlighted_dates = $dateArray;
```

Comment: Don't build a string of dates and cast that to an array, because then you'll have a sinqle array entry containing a long string..... build the array of dates as you iterate through the query resultset.... `$dateArray = array(); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $dateArray[] = $row["Date"]; 
            }
`

Comment: And stop using the old, deprecated MySQL extension..... it's 2016 now, switch to using MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Thanks Mark. Working perfect now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your code as @Mark Baker suggested:-

```
$Date = array(); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
   $Date[] = $row["Date"]; 
}
```

Now you will get `$Date` as `Array('2016-12-03', '2016-12-14', '2016-12-25')` what you want.

Note:- `mysql_*` is deprecated now, Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created a 3 value array:

```
Array('2016-12-03', '2016-12-14', '2016-12-25' );
```

You've created a 1 value array:

```
Array("'2016-12-03', '2016-12-14', '2016-12-25'");
```

Notice the 3 strings versus 1 string.

Comment: no, i have 3 strings separated by a comma. look - $Date.= "'".$row["Date"]."'".", ";

Comment: No, you have 3 substrings connected by a comma, they are all concatenated into one string...